# How do you start at the same element in a nested for loop?

Tags: python

I'm having difficulty understanding how to make a nested for loop start at the "same" element.

Here is part of my code:

```
for elem1 in sentence2:
    for elem2 in bigram_list:
        if (elem1 == vocab_list[int(elem2[0]) - 1]):
            file.write("elem1: " + elem1 + "\n")
            file.write("vocab: " + vocab_list[int(elem2[0]) - 1] + "\n")
            index3 = index3 + 1
            for (sameElem2 in bigram_list):
                if (sentence2[index3] == vocab_list[int(sameElem2[1]) - 1]
```

The thing is, each elem2 in bigram_list contains indices elem2[0], elem2[1], elem2[2]

I'm trying to check whether an element at elem[0] in bigram_list is equal to another element in my sentence2_list, and if it does, I want to be able to start looping through the next index, i.e. elem2[1] but still be at that same element in the bigram_list and check if it's equal to the next element in the sentence2_list

But that's where I'm stuck. I want to go forward, not backwards :)

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to change the starting point of your iteration as you go. If that's so, you can achieve this through some simple slicing:

```
for i, elem1 in enumerate(bigram_list):
    for elem2 in bigram_list[i:]:
        # Do something
```

For a bit of explanation, `enumerate` is a python function that simply returns both the index currently used, and the element in a single tuple, meaning you can access the two as done above.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but when I tried that I get an error saying "slice indices must be integers or None or have an _index_method"

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu Thought you were using a slightly different structure. Updated version should work.

Comment: thanks! I guess the question I asked was not for the problem I'm facing :) ....my actual problem is how do I "maintain" and "reuse" the same element in my nest for loop?...Meaning how do I use the "current" index of the element in the first for loop and start that index in the nested for loop instead of "moving" to the next element in the list? I hope I make sense :)

Comment: each element in bigram_list has 3 indices, my first for loop checks if the value in elem[0] of bigram_list == elem of sentence2, if it does, I want to have a nested for loop that starts at that same elem iteration, but using index 2, because the elem in bigram_list has elem[0] elem[1] and elem[2], I hope it was clear

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu That is... less clear. If you added a sample input and a desired output that would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing instead:

```
for elem1 in sentence2:
    for i in range(0,len(bigram_list)):
        elem2 = int(bigram_list[i])-1
        if (elem1 == vocab_list[elem2]):
            file.write("elem1: " + elem1 + "\n")
            file.write("vocab: " + vocab_list[elem2] + "\n")
            if i+1 < len(bigram_list):
                nextElem2 = int(bigram_list[i+1])-1
                index3 = index3 + 1 # Make sure that you want to increment 'index3' here and not inside the 'if'
                if sentence2[index3] == vocab_list[nextElem2]:
                    ...
```

Comment: Slicing in this case is cleaner and more efficient than indexing.

Comment: I cant use i as an index, because I need to be able to access indices of each element in my bigram_list

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu You can still use indexing, but chaining them, e.g. `bigram_list[i][1]`, but this does make things cluttered and less intuitive.

Comment: You can still use `currElem2[index]` as you did before with `elem2[index]` (updated the answer in order to make it more clear)...

Comment: hello barak, I updated my question, I wasn't asking the right question :)

Comment: Hello Tokugawa Ieysu. Now the question becomes unclear. What is the difference between `elem2` and `sameElem2`?

Comment: there is really no difference, besides the indices of elem2. Each index of elem2 has a different value, I want the nested for loop to start at that same elem, but loop through a different index because it contains different values, does that make sense?

Comment: OK, answer updated (I hope I understood you correctly).

Comment: thanks for the update, but unfortunately I dont believe it's what I'm expecting, because I'm getting an list index out of range. I'll try to be clearer. Basically, each "elem2" in bigram_list contains elem2[0] = (some arbitrary float), elem2[1] = (some arbitrary float), and elem2[2] = (arbitrary float). The first loop accesses elem2[0] and compares it with elem1 (a word) in sentence2. If it matches, I want to use the nested for loop to loop through elem2[1] and compare it with the next word in sentence2, because at eaach iteration of elem2[1] is a different float value, is this cleare now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46623/discussion-between-tokugawa-ieysu-and-barak-manos)

Comment: unfortunately thats not what I was looking for. :( Can we discuss this in chat so maybe I can describe it more?